# Get compressed file size in Squashfs

Tags: squashfs

Is there any way to get the compressed file size in squashfs?
I need to get every single compressed file in squashfs.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354593/investigating-squashfs-compression-ratio)?